# Jar files in libs folder are not used in Android Gradle build

Tags: android, adt, gradle

i just started to play with the gradle build system for Android.

However i'm not able build one of my projects. It depends on a jar in the libs/ folder.

Doing `gradle build` fails in the `compileDebug` task because all of the classes from the jar file are missing.

It is a library project! Here is my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
    target='android-16'
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest {
                srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            }
            java {
                srcDir 'src'
            }
            res {
                srcDir 'res'
            }
            assets {
                srcDir 'assets'
            }
            resources {
                srcDir 'src'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Am i missing something obvious?

Goddchen

Answer (score 59, accepted):

just found the answer myself:

Seems like the current version of the Android Gradle plugin doesn't look for jars in the libs/ folder. So you have to add them yourself:

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/mylib.jar')
}
```

or

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

Place this within the `android` namespace like this:

```
android {
    target = "android-15"

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just in case none of the solutions worked for you, you may want to try to provide the path to the *.jar manually:

```
compile files('../<your-library-folder>/<your-library>.jar')
```

The `'../'` part means that Gradle will search for the library starting from the root projects folder (not app module).