# How to add external jar library file to Intellij Idea android project

Tags: android, jar, intellij-idea, gradle

I have tried this: [Correct way to add external jars (lib/*.jar) to an IntelliJ IDEA project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project?rq=1)
 to add a external jar library file "temp.jar" under lib folder(I have created) and mark it as Library. Then I build/ re-build the project, the errors still said that package com.example.temp doesn't exist. I am using Intellij IDEA 13.1 Free version and Gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using Gradle I believe you also should modify build.gradle for your module.
In section dependencies add line like this:

compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

like in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13072692/1570833
Hope this helps! 
Cheers